# How can I track user activity in a JHipster Application

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

I want to track all the user activity in my Jhipster Application including Login and everything else.What could be the best practice of doing it. Jhipster already has logging and Audits but I have no idea of how to use it.

Comment: Have you tried this module: https://github.com/hipster-labs/generator-jhipster-entity-audit ?

Comment: Works only with mongo and SQL Databases.Unfortunately, I am using cassandra